# Recreate Xaml in Code

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

I've got some Xaml (WPF) that I'm trying to re-create in code. I think I'm close but I'm having a bit of trouble... here's my Xaml:

```
<ListView Name="lbDevices" SelectionChanged="lbDevices_SelectionChanged" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"></WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Style>
                </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!-- This is a custom control -->
                            <l:HaDeviceDisplayer DataContext="{Binding .}" ></l:HaDeviceDisplayer>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The above gives me a perfect display of what I need. It looks like this:

Here's my attempt at re-creating it in code:

```
            GridView gv = new GridView();
            gv.AllowsColumnReorder = false;

            var hiddenStyle = new Style();
            gv.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle = hiddenStyle;
            gv.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(FrameworkElement.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed));

            ItemsPanelTemplate panelTemplate = new ItemsPanelTemplate();
            var fact = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(WrapPanel));
            fact.SetValue(WrapPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
            fact.SetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden);

            var binding = new Binding() {
                RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(ScrollContentPresenter), 1),
                Path = new PropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.ActualWidth)")
            };
            fact.SetBinding(WrapPanel.WidthProperty, binding);

            panelTemplate.VisualTree = fact;
            lbDevices.ItemsPanel = panelTemplate;

            GridViewColumn c1 = new GridViewColumn();
            c1.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("DeviceDisplayer");
            lbDevices.View = gv;
```

A couple of notes. Instead of trying to re-create the DataTemplate exactly as I had it in Xaml, I stuck it in a `UserControl.Resources` tag in the Xaml. I then use the FindResource to set the CellTemplate.

So here's my problem. When I do the above, the layout ends up looking like this:

[image: Broken list]

Notice the very small orange dot... there's about a dozen of them that are visible only because selecting an item highlights it with an orange border. For same reason each list item is small. The trouble is - how do I make it "normal" sized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did figure out why my code didn't match the XAML.  Instead, I ended up using XAML and then just creating a reference to the View to re-use for later.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you're looking for, but I'd use an ItemsControl with a WrapPanel as the ItemPanelTemplate and use an ItemTemplateSelector to style each item depending on the type, rather than manually adding items to a ListView. you could just use a WrapPanel to get the same look, but I'm guessing you want it to be flexible.